# Bug when removing columns from Nebula Grid using Visual Range Support

Tags: java, swt, jface, nebula

I'm trying to dispose of columns and add new ones to a Nebula Grid, the data in the table won't change I just want to be able to change the columns used.

I am getting a bug where the Grid is throwing index out of bounds exceptions as it's iterating through a list of existing columns but using a value "endColumnIndex" to stop the loop, but the endColumnIndex value is bigger than the list of new columns.

I believe this is due to using Visual Range Support, and the value for the current on screen columns is not being updated as I am removing them.

I have written a class to reproduce this bug here, and am hoping someone has a workaround for this issue:

```
import org.eclipse.nebula.jface.gridviewer.GridTableViewer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.jface.gridviewer.GridViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.GridColumn;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.GridItem;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.GridVisibleRangeSupport;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.GridVisibleRangeSupport.RangeChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.GridVisibleRangeSupport.VisibleRangeChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class GridRangeChangeBug {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(800, 800);

        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        Button go = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        go.setText("Reproduce Bug");

        final GridTableViewer viewer = new GridTableViewer(shell, SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
        viewer.getGrid().setLayoutData(
                new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        viewer.getGrid().setHeaderVisible(true);

        GridVisibleRangeSupport rangeSupport = GridVisibleRangeSupport.createFor(viewer.getGrid());
        rangeSupport.addRangeChangeListener(new VisibleRangeChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void rangeChanged(RangeChangedEvent event) {


            }
        });


        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            GridViewerColumn col = new GridViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
            col.getColumn().setWidth(30);
            col.getColumn().setText("" + i);
        }

        go.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                for (GridColumn c : viewer.getGrid().getColumns()) {
                    c.dispose();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    GridViewerColumn col = new GridViewerColumn(viewer,
                            SWT.NONE);
                    col.getColumn().setWidth(30);
                    col.getColumn().setText("" + i);
                }
            }

        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```